# MongoDB - count items using addToSet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with a collection called "submissions" that includes mission data for a game. Every time you submit your answer to the question/mission a document is saved to the submissions collection.

A typical document looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0c99dffea598002fdb6ec9"), 
    "status" : "Accepted", 
    "missionAcceptanceDate" : NumberInt(1527526261), 
    "submissionDate" : NumberInt(1527552495), 
    "location" : "", 
    "approvalDate" : null, 
    "mission_id" : ObjectId("5b0c5b10fea598002fdb6ec6"), 
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5b0c99d0fea598002fdb6ec7")
}
```

I need to build a query that can determine the following:

1. Counts the total submissions per grouping by status between a date range,
2. Counts the Total number of submissions by mission_id per each grouping.

Below is what I have so far ("cutting out some info..."):

**QUERY**:

```
db.submissions.aggregate(
        { $match: {
            "submissionDate": {
                "$gte": NumberInt(1527901260), //Fri, 1 Jun 2018 18:00:01 PDT
                "$lte": NumberInt(1530831600) //Thu, 5 Jul 2018 16:00:00 PDT
            }
          }
        },
        {$project: 
            {_id:1,
            status: 1,
            missionAcceptanceDate: 1,
            submissionDate: 1,
            approvalDate: 1,
            user_id: 1,
            mission_id: 1
            }
        },
        {$group: {
                    _id: { status: "$status" },
                    statusTotal: { $sum: 1 },
                    mission_id: { $addToSet: "$mission_id" },
                    }
         }

)
```

**RESULT**:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "Rejected"
    }, 
    "statusTotal" : 16.0, 
    "mission_id" : [
        ObjectId("5b0edbfafea598002fdb6f3a"), 
        ObjectId("5b0f0131fea598002fdb6f43"), 
        ObjectId("5b0eded6fea598002fdb6f3d"), 
        ...
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "Approved"
    }, 
    "statusTotal" : 592.0, 
    "mission_id" : [
        ObjectId("5b391cf4e177c700308dd0ef"), 
        ObjectId("5b36a0d172b5240030d304be"), 
        ObjectId("5b3558276a0f950030db1732"), 
        ...
    ]
}
```

This is a great, but I also need to know the Total Number of Times each "mission_id" was "Rejected" or "Approved". The desired out come should look something like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "Rejected"
    }, 
    "statusTotal" : 16.0, 
    "mission_id" : [

        ...
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b0edbfafea598002fdb6f3a"), count: 3 },
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b0f0131fea598002fdb6f43"), count: 5},
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b0eded6fea598002fdb6f3d"), count: 2 } 
        ...
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "Approved"
    }, 
    "statusTotal" : 592.0, 
    "missionData" : [ 
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b391cf4e177c700308dd0ef"), count: 23 },
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b36a0d172b5240030d304be"), count: 45},
        { mission_id: ObjectId("5b3558276a0f950030db1732"), count: 15 } 
        ...
    ]
}
```

I tried using $size, $sum, $count, even using a second $group with {$sum:1} for each mission_id, but just can't figure it out. Any help with this would be so much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra grouping before your group if I understand your question correctly.

Something like

```
db.submissions.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"submissionDate":{"$gte":NumberInt(1527901260),"$lte":NumberInt(1530831600)}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"status":"$status","mission_id":"$mission_id"},
    "missionTotal":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.status",
    "statusTotal":{"$sum":"$missionTotal"},
    "mission_id":{"$push":{"mission_id":"$_id.mission_id","count":"$missionTotal"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: YES!! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I ended up including a $look to match the mission_id with it's name from the missions collection.